# Elasticsearch index search for currency $ and £ signs

Tags: elasticsearch

In some of my documents I have $ or £ symbols. I want to search for £ and retrieve documents containing that symbol. I've gone through [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html) but I'm getting some cognitive dissonance.

```
# Delete the `my_index` index
DELETE /my_index    

# Create a custom analyzer
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "&_to_and": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "&=> and ",
            "$=> dollar "
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip",
            "&_to_and"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns "the", "quick", "and", "brown", "fox" just as the documentation states:

```
# Test out the new analyzer
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&text=The%20quick%20%26%20brown%20fox
```

This returns "the", "quick", "dollar", "brown", "fox"

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&text=The%20quick%20%24%20brown%20fox
```

Adding some records:

```
PUT /my_index/test/1
{
  "title": "The quick & fast fox"
}    

PUT /my_index/test/1
{
  "title": "The daft fox owes me $100"
}
```

I would have thought if I search for "dollar", I would get a result? Instead I get no results:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search
{ "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "dollar"
    }
  }
}
```

Or even using '$' with an analyzer:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search
{ "query": {
  "query_string": {
    "query": "dollar10",
    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you check with term vertors the actual analyzed data: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you specify a custom analyzer but you never use that. If you use [term vertors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) you can verify that. So follow that steps:

When creating and index set custom analyzer for the `title field:

```
GET /my_index

{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "&_to_and": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "&=> and ",
            "$=> dollar "
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip",
            "&_to_and"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, "mappings" :{
    "test" : {
      "properties" : {
        "title" : {
          "type":"string",
          "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Insert data:

```
PUT my_index/test/1

{
  "title": "The daft fox owes me $100"
}
```

Check for term vectors:

```
GET /my_index/test/1/_termvectors?fields=title
```

Response:

```
{
   "_index":"my_index",
   "_type":"test",
   "_id":"1",
   "_version":1,
   "found":true,
   "took":3,
   "term_vectors":{
      "title":{
         "field_statistics":{
            "sum_doc_freq":6,
            "doc_count":1,
            "sum_ttf":6
         },
         "terms":{
            "daft":{
               "term_freq":1,
               "tokens":[
                  {
                     "position":1,
                     "start_offset":4,
                     "end_offset":8
                  }
               ]
            },
            "dollar100":{       <-- You can see it here
               "term_freq":1,
               "tokens":[
                  {
                     "position":5,
                     "start_offset":21,
                     "end_offset":25
                  }
               ]
            },
            "fox":{
               "term_freq":1,
               "tokens":[
                  {
                     "position":2,
                     "start_offset":9,
                     "end_offset":12
                  }
               ]
            },
            "me":{
               "term_freq":1,
               "tokens":[
                  {
                     "position":4,
                     "start_offset":18,
                     "end_offset":20
                  }
               ]
            },
            "owes":{
               "term_freq":1,
               "tokens":[
                  {
                     "position":3,
                     "start_offset":13,
                     "end_offset":17
                  }
               ]
            },
            "the":{
               "term_freq":1,
               "tokens":[
                  {
                     "position":0,
                     "start_offset":0,
                     "end_offset":3
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now search:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "dollar100"
    }
  }
}
```

That will find the match. But searching with query string as:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search

{ "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "dollar100"
    }
  }
}
```

won't find anything. Because it searches special _all field. And as I can see it aggregates fields as they are not analyzed:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "dollar100"
    }
  }
}
```

does not find a result. But:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "$100"
    }
  }
}
```

finds. I am not sure but the reason for that can be that the default analyzer is not the custom analyzer. To set a custom analyzer as default check:

[Changing the default analyzer in ElasticSearch or LogStash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776784/changing-the-default-analyzer-in-elasticsearch-or-logstash)

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-we-can-change-Elasticsearch-default-analyzer-td4040411.html

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/148kwsxzee/overriding-built-in-analyzer-and-set-it-as-default

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-to-set-the-default-analyzer-td3935275.html

Comment: Thank you so much!