# Elastic search Nest C# - How to Ignore casing in Sorting in a generic way

Tags: c#, sorting, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to build a helper to create a dynamic search using Nest Elastic Search. The sorting works fine but it is also sorting based on casing. This is my generic Search

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Search(ISearchQueryHelper<T> searchSpecs)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new SearchRequest<T>(this.indexName)
        {
            Size = 5000,
            Query = searchSpecs.GetQuery(),
            Sort = searchSpecs.GetSorts()
        };

        var response = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(request);
            
        return response.Documents;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

and I'm indexing documents like this

```
public virtual async Task<string> IndexAsync(T document)
{
    var response = await elasticClient.IndexAsync(document, idx => idx.Index(indexName));
    if (response.Result == Result.Error)
    {
        throw response.OriginalException;
    }

    return response.Id;
}
```

And in my Helper class, I'm adding sorts like this

```
private List<ISort> Sorts { get; }

public void AddSort(Expression<Func<T, object>> field, bool isAscending)
{
    Sorts.Add(new FieldSort
    {
        Field = Infer.Field<T>(field),
        Order = isAscending ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending
    });
}
```

Is there a way to ignore case on sort? Something like `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` when comparing strings.

I've seen lots of thread about this but all of it are using `Client.Indices.Create()` instead of `Client.IndexAsync()` and all are class specific too which will require me to map every field I want to ignore case sort.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort Es side to win time, so you need to tell elastic how to analyse / sort your data.

You cant use default mappings analyser, as you notice, in order to dodge to create a new mappings for each index, you could use a generic function.

If you call analyser default, he will overwrite the default analyser, this is that you are looking for.

Call this function only 1 time, before indexing the first document, you can use Client.Indices.Exist to know if your index need to be created.

```
public void SetMapping<T>(string index) where T : class {
    var re2 = Client.Indices.Create(index, c => c
                   .Map<T>(m => m
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                        )
                        .AutoMap()
                )
                .Settings(
                    s =>
                        s.Analysis(
                            a =>
                                a
                                .Analyzers(
                                    an =>
                                        an.Custom("default", cad =>
                                                cad.Tokenizer("standard").Filters(new string[] {
                                                    "lowercase",
                                                    "asciifolding"
                                                }))
                            )
                        )
                )
                );
}
```

note: Nest client is not perfect, for specific use like this, it could be easy to create your index using a json with lowlevelclient or a curl.

The post about the default mappins modification:
[Changing the default analyzer in ElasticSearch or LogStash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776784/changing-the-default-analyzer-in-elasticsearch-or-logstash)

Comment: thanks for this. I actually found a workaround on my end without extra configurations on ES so I'll just settle with it. I'm converting everything to documents before actually indexing it so I'll just lowercase the necessary fields during conversion. This is way easier for me than dealing all these extra configs just to correct the sorting. I can't accept this as an answer since I haven't really used this but you can have my upvote. Thanks